# Non public links via htaccess Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to Redirect using htaccess to a non public file?

For example, instead of redirecting to 'latest_installer.zip' in /downloads/installers I'd like to Redirect to a file outside of the public_html root folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with Apache using mod_alias:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't access the apache configurations files as I am on a shared server.